# Why am I unable to use tf.nn.conv2d when I call it through an other function?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to do data augmentation over a dataset.
I have different kind of modifiers, one of them is the Gaussian Blur.
I used to map it with `tf.nn.conv3d` but in order to make it faster, I changed it to `tf.nn.conv2d` (using 3d was not optimal). However now, when I run it, I get

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Generic conv implementation only supports NHWC tensor format for now.
```

I don't understand why because I'm already trying to run it with `data_format='NHWC'`.

Here is the code :

```py
my current file :
with tf.name_scope('DataAugmentation'):
    for modifier in modifiers:
        def apply_modifier(t_imgs,t_lbls,t_ranges,t_img_paths):
            t_imgs, t_lbls = modifier.apply_to(t_imgs, t_lbls)
                   return t_imgs,t_lbls,t_ranges,t_img_paths

        ds = ds.map(apply_modifier)
```

In an other file, the method of the modifier which raises the issue  :

```py
    self.k_conv = ........
    def apply_to(self, t_imgs, t_lbls):
        with tf.name_scope('GaussianBlur'):            
            t_imgs = tf.nn.conv2d(t_imgs,self.k_conv,
                       strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
                       padding='SAME',
                       data_format='NHWC'
                       )
            return (t_imgs, t_lbls)
```

The very strange point is that I can run the program if I declare the function in my current file instead of in an other file where I define the class modifier :

```py
        with tf.name_scope('DataAugmentation'):
            for modifier in modifiers:
                if modifier.m.NAME=='GaussianBlur':
                    k_conv = create.random_k_conv()
                    def apply_modifier(t_imgs,t_lbls,t_ranges,t_img_paths):

                        t_imgs = tf.nn.conv2d(t_imgs,k_conv,
                                              strides=[1,1,1,1],
                                              padding='SAME'
                                              )
                        return t_imgs,t_lbls,t_ranges,t_img_paths
                else:
                    def apply_modifier(t_imgs,t_lbls,t_ranges,t_img_paths):
                        t_imgs, t_lbls = modifier.apply_to(t_imgs, t_lbls)
                        return t_imgs,t_lbls,t_ranges,t_img_paths
                ds = ds.map(apply_modifier)
```

The type of my dataset is

````
<BatchDataset shapes: ((?, 500, 500, 1), (?, 6, 6, 5), (?, 2), (?,)), types (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.string)>```

I really have no idea why the second code runs but not the first one, it s been a few days I am stuck.

Thank you for reading, I hope someone could help.
````

Comment: Please add your input datatype and shape. Also why define function inside for loop?

Comment: I defined the function inside the loop because it depends on the modifier. So for each modifier of the list modifiers, I define apply_modifier and use it to map the dataset.

Comment: The point of defining function, is that you can pass argument to it and reuse it in different cases

Comment: I would like to do it but I can't pass any argument in the argument map_fun of map

Answer (score 1):

I found why it didn't work, so I answer to my own question for anyone having a similar issue.

In the case where I have an error, the architecture of my code forces the tf.nn.conv2d to run on the CPU meanwhile the layer_optimizer changes the version of tf.nn.conv2d to a version which can only run on the GPU.

Adding `config.graph_options.rewrite_options.layout_optimizer = 2` solves the problem.

[this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26411) helped me to solve the problem.